# Confusion regarding code access security with unverifiable code

Tags: c#, code-access-security

I am confused about what I need to do in order to correctly "set up" my unverifiable method so that it conforms to code access security guidelines.

---

Given the following method

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
private extern void DoStuffUnverifiable();
```

which is deemed unverifiable by `PEVerify`, what attributes do I absolutely need to apply to the method definition?

- `[SecurityCritical]`?
- `[SecuritySafeCritical]`?

How do I decide between those two? Further,

- do I need to set `[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]`?
- If so, do I use `SecurityAction.Demand` or something else?

Are there any other attributes I definitely *need* to apply? Are there any that I *could* apply, although not neccessary?

Comment: What is the usage scenario?  MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef is quite unusual and normally only appears in C++ code.  Which is never verifiable.  CAS is unusual as well, deprecated at .NET 4 and replaced by a sandboxing model.

Comment: The actual method body is implemented in CIL directly. The CIL is not verifiable, but that is by design. @HansPassant Does the new sandboxing model mean I do not have to annotate the method with any attributes at all? Will security issues automatically be handled by the framework / execution engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the transparency model, security-critical methods are marked with the `[SecurityCritical]` attribute:

```
[SecurityCritical]
public Key GetTVRoomKey() { ... }
```

All “dangerous” methods (containing code that the CLR considers could breach security and allow an inmate to
escape) must be marked with `[SecurityCritical]` or `[SecuritySafeCritical]`. This comprises:

- Unverifiable (unsafe) methods
- Methods that call unmanaged code via P/Invoke or COM interop
- Methods that Assert permissions or call link-demanding methods
- Methods that call [SecurityCritical] methods
- Methods that override virtual [SecurityCritical] methods

`[SecurityCritical]` means “this method could allow a partially trusted caller to escape a sandbox”.
`[SecuritySafeCritical]` means “this method does security-critical things—but with appropriate safeguards
and so is safe for partially trusted callers”.

---

So yes, in your case - `[SecurityCritical]` is surely needed, if you want extra safety, use `[SecuritySafeCritical]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Before also awarding the bounty, I would be very happy if you could answer two more questions that arose when I read your answer: 1. is the "transparency model" the same thing Hans Passant called "sandboxing model"? Is what you describe the up-to-date way of CAS or was it also obsoleted with .NET 4? 2. Do I really need to mark all callers of the `[SecurityCritical]` method `[SecurityCritical]` as well?